# How to Filter/Remove empty objects in lowdb

Tags: node.js, lodash

I'm just learning how to use lowdb. In my testing, I created a small database that has some empty objects. I'd like to learn how to remove these from the database. Below is the database I'm working with.

```
{
  "posts": [
    {},
    {
      "name": "hello"
    },
    {
      "name": "good"
    },
    {
      "name": "foo"
    },
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.get('posts')
    .remove(_.isEmpty)
    .write()
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Stucco/u36bzdLx/3/